# create a webform with multiple jsp

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am new to liferay, and want to create a custom web form portlet having multiple jsp. 
like on one jsp i have to display the all details for the user i.e first name last name etc with next button (it will redirect the user to another jsp) that contains a message box with submit button. 
after click on submit button the data from both jsp will be save in database!
i have created a register.jsp page

```
<%@include file="/init.jsp" %>
<html>
<body>
<form action="<portlet:actionURL></portlet:actionURL>"  method="post" name="userForm" onsubmit="return Account();">
<b>First Name:</b>
<input type="text" name="<portlet:namespace/>firstName" id="<portlet:namespace/>firstName"/><br/>
<b>Last Name:</b> 
<input type="text" name="<portlet:namespace/>lastName" id="<portlet:namespace/>lastName"/><br/>
<b>E-mail:</b> 
<input type="text" name="<portlet:namespace/>eMail" id="<portlet:namespace/>eMail"/><br/>
<b>Age:</b>
           <select name="<portlet:namespace/>age">
             <option value="20">20</option>
             <option value="20-25">20-25</option>
             <option value="25-30">25-30</option>
             <option value="30-35">30-35</option>
             <option value="35+">35+</option>
           </select><br/>
<b>Region:</b>
           <select name="<portlet:namespace/>region">
             <option value="east">east</option>
             <option value="west">west</option>
             <option value="north">north</option>
             <option value="south">south</option>
           </select><br/>
 <b>Gender</b><br/>
<input type="radio" name="<portlet:namespace/>sex" value="male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="<portlet:namespace/>sex" value="female">Female<br/>
</form>
<br/><a href="<portlet:renderURL/>"> <button class="btn btn-primary">Go Back</button></a>
<portlet:renderURL var="submitDetailURL">
<portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/submit.jsp"/>
</portlet:renderURL>
<a href="<%=submitDetailURL %>"> <button class="btn btn-primary">Next</button></a>
```

and the next button will redirect to submit.jsp page

```
<%@include file="/init.jsp" %>
<html>
<body>
<form action='<portlet:actionURL></portlet:actionURL>'  method="post" name="valid" onsubmit="return Account();">
 <b>Message:</b>
 <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="<portlet:namespace/>address">
</textarea>
<a href="<portlet:renderURL/>"> <button class="btn btn-primary">Go Back</button></a>
<input type="submit" name="addUser" id="addUser" value="Submit">
</tr>   
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and my service.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE service-builder PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Service Builder 6.1.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-service-builder_6_1_0.dtd">
<service-builder package-path="com.yogisha">
    <author>Sony</author>
    <namespace>yogisha</namespace>
    <entity name="Campaign" local-service="true" remote-service="false">

        <column name="campaignId" type="long" primary="true"></column>
        <column name="firstName" type="String"></column>
        <column name="lastName" type="String"></column>
        <column name="eMail" type="String"></column>
        <column name="age" type="String"></column>
        <column name="region" type="String"></column>
        <column name="sex" type="String"></column>
        <column name="content" type="String"></column>
    </entity>
</service-builder>
```

but it seems like its not working. can anyone tell my what i am missing?

Comment: What is not working? Where and when is it not working? What did you do yourself to diagnose the issue? Please re-visit [ask].

Comment: @rene system is not creating field for `lastName` and `region` in database

Comment: You should add that to your question (use the  [**edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24854037/edit) link)

Comment: Does it have to have a 'Next' button or could you tabulate the display similar to the way `My Account -> Account Settings` appears. What is the `Account` function doing? Have you looked into the [taglibs](http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Alloy+UI+Forms+%28aui%29), they throw in a bunch of extraneous whitespace but provide a consistent look-n-feel and take care of some of the stuff you are doing "manually" like prepending `<portlet:namespace/>`.